# wp_ajax add_action fuction won't fire on custom jQuery action

Tags: plugin-development, functions, ajax, jquery, actions

In general, I try to apply a "load more post" functionality to a loop, but I am failing to fire a PHP function within a plugin.

The PHP function is supposed to fire using a custom jQuery action with value "load_more". I use he following add_action functions to fire the PHP function:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_more', 'load_more_ajax_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more', 'load_more_ajax_handler' );
```

Within the jQuery script, I am able to console out following value:

```
{action: "load_more", query: "{"posts_per_page":3,"post_type":"artikler","paged"…_page":"50","no_found_rows":false,"order":"DESC"}", max: "4", page: "1", results: "10"}
```

I have never been able to fire the PHP function using the wp_ajax add_action method and according to documentation, I do not see what I am missing.

I initialize the jQuery script using following PHP function:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wordpress_my_load_more_scripts' );

function wordpress_my_load_more_scripts() 
{
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    $query_args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 3,
        'post_type'         => 'artikler',
        'paged'             => $paged
    );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $query_args);

    if (!isset( $wp_query ))
    {
        debug_to_console("Query is NULL!");

        return;
    }

    wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', plugins_url( 'myloadmore.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );

    $postArray = array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), 
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'results' => $wp_query->found_posts
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'wordpress_load_more_params', $postArray);

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
}
```

The jQuery script containing the custom action is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $(".wordpress_load_more").click(function(){

        var button = $(this), data = {
            action      :   'load_more',
            query       :   wordpress_load_more_params.posts,
            max         :   wordpress_load_more_params.max_page,
            page        :   wordpress_load_more_params.current_page,
            results     :   wordpress_load_more_params.results

        };

        console.log(data);

        $.ajax(
        {
            url     :   wordpress_load_more_params.ajaxurl, 
            type    :   'POST',
            data    :   data,
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) 
            {
                console.log("Loading");

                button.text('Indlæser...');
            },
            success : function( data )
            {
                console.log("Success");

                if(data) 
                { 
                    console.log("We got data!");
                    console.log(wordpress_load_more_params.current_page);
                    console.log(wordpress_load_more_params.max_page);

                    button.text( 'Flere indlæg' ).prev().before(data); 
                    wordpress_load_more_params.current_page++;

                    if ( wordpress_load_more_params.current_page == wordpress_load_more_params.max_page ) 
                    {
                        console.log("Last page! Remove button");

                        button.remove(); 
                    }

                } else {

                    console.log("No data! Remove button");

                    button.remove();
                }
            },
            error: function() 
            {
                console.log("jQuery error");            
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The PHP function I can't call using the custom jQuery action is this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_more', 'load_more_ajax_handler' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more', 'load_more_ajax_handler' );

function load_more_ajax_handler()
{
    global $wp_query;

    debug_to_console("Finaly, load_more_ajax_handler() function is succesfully called!!!");

    $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );

    debug_to_console($args);

    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    query_posts( $args );

    if( have_posts() ) :

        echo "We have post(s)!";

        while( have_posts() ): the_post();

            the_title();

        endwhile;

    endif;

    debug_to_console("Die!");

    wp_die(); 
}
```

According to whatever documentation I read and similar examples I find, I am not able to trigger this PHP function is wp_ajax. How come?

Please find example page where i apply this plugin, right here - https://www.uvjagtpro.dk/arkiv/

Comment: I try on the page and I see a response. do you solve the problem ?

Comment: Not sure I understand you comment. The problem is not solved. Let me know, if I need to elaborate on anything above.

Comment: when I click on "Flere indlæg" I see the AJAX result then for me there is no more problem.

Comment: I'm wondering why you're sending that huge object in `query` parameter? Where only few items could do the work. Can you try with only `posts_per_page and post_type`?

Comment: I am also seeing the console data when I click "Flere indlæg". I will note that you do not need to `json_decode` the query args. The ajax is firing just fine.

Comment: The only problem I see is `query_posts()` is not getting any posts. Can you try to build the `$args` array without the help of `$_POST['query']`? Just for a check..

Comment: @SohanZaman - I agree. It was not necessary to send the whole query parameter. I removed it away from the jQuery script.

I also tried defining the $args without using the $_POST['query'] within the load_more_ajax_handler() function. However - I still can't fire the functions using the jQuery action and i don't get why.

Comment: @NathanPowell - I tried removing the "json_decode" from the query args. It worked out fine, but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Feel free to inspect my plugin code: https://github.com/UVjagtPro/UVjagtPRO-Load-more-post-list

Comment: You need to send your response back to the script so it will do something with it to display. Currently, it is logging fine, but doing an `echo` will not result in desired output. Use `wp_send_json()` in php and in javascript use the response to manipulate the DOM with the desired output.

Comment: @NathanPowell is correct. Now it's working fine. You need to remove all the console debugging lines and return the output in json format. Output buffers can help here. You can place `ob_start();` before your loop and `wp_send_json(ob_get_clean());` after loop. And don't echo or debug anything else.